# IOS programmatically get keyboard letters of active language

Tags: ios, keyboard

Is it possible to programmatically get all keyboard letters for the selected language?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to have an input method through custom buttons in iOS8 extension because keyboard is not allowed.  Not sure if this will be accepted or rejected by apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will store and log them:

```
static inline NSArray * charactersInCharacterSet(NSCharacterSet *charSet) {
    NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSData * data = [charSet bitmapRepresentation];
    const char* bytes = [data bytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8192; ++i) {
        if (bytes[i >> 3] & (((unsigned int)1) << (i & 7))) {
            [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unichar)i]];
        }
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}
```

called like so:

```
NSCharacterSet * charSet = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"sr_Cyrl_ME"]objectForKey:NSLocaleExemplarCharacterSet];
NSArray * chars = charactersInCharacterSet(charSet);
for (NSString *str in chars) {
        NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

This will give you a tough time with some Asian country alphabets, but it's returning latin based language alphabets just fine. It will probably need to be rebuffed to handle some of the character based alphabets.

In fact, let me add some source material for you to take a look at this in more depth:

http://samplecodebank.blogspot.com/2013_06_09_archive.html

One more method, only because I knew I had this sitting around somewhere and it's a whole heck of a lot easier to implement, but this is limited to the section index titles of, for example, the index of a UITableView.

```
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles]];

for (id obj in characters) {
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
}
```

Comment: Yes, UILocalizedIndexCollation is what I was going to suggest.

Comment: @matt the only terrible part about the index way is that it's not returning the full character set with tildas and accent marks, this is with English only, but maybe this IS different in other languages or maybe the OP just wants the actual index of letters, either way, the index way is so much easier and straight forward

Comment: Is it possible to get the location of each letter in the keyboard? Is there a keyboard class that would return this kind of information? thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: ive looked around and haven't found anything like that, but I've only looked just on a surface level so far, ill dive deeper later tonight or tomorrow